# Doctrine 2 and PostgreSQL: How to get only the time from a "time without timezone" attribute

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I Have the following table on PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE horary
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_office_horary'::regclass),
  day character(3),
  start time without time zone,
  end time without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT pk_horary PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

A piece of my PHP Code:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="time", name="start")
 */
protected $start;

/**
 * @Column(type="time", name="end")
 */
protected $end;
```

When the system returns the **json_encode(horary)** I get this result:

```
{
    "start": {
       "date": "2014-04-10 08:00:00",
       "timezone_type": 3,
       "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    },
    "end": {
        "date": "2014-04-10 12:00:00",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
    }
}
```

If I change the Column type in PHP mapping from **time** to **string** I get **exactly what I need**:

```
{
    "start": "08:00:00",
    "end": "12:00:00"
}
```

If the data type in PostgreSQL is "time without timezone" why Doctrine brings all the data related to timezone? Why I should map those "time" fields as string in order to get only the time?

Is there a way to map the columns as "time" and get the same result I want (a straightforward information about the time)?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: It's presumably reading the server TimeZone setting. This is really an ORM thing, not a PostgreSQL thing.

Comment: Yes, it's an ORM matter. For sure. But I'm wondering how to solve that.

Comment: According to documentation doctrine2 can map time field only to DateTime. But you can create your own mapping type that will map to a PHP Time object like this: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html